# Cannot Check Collisions -Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, rigid-bodies

I am currently developing an AI demo for a fighting game using Unity game engine. I wrote an `OnTriggerEnter` that detects fists or kicks; however it detects actions if and only if the characters move. I tried `rigidboy.WakeUp()` and `rigidbody.AddForce( new Vector3(0,0,0) )` but they did not solve the problem.

Problem is like this:

For example, I kick the other character, and my character's leg enters, and exits the collider but, `OnTriggerEnter` is not called until I move my character.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
function OnTriggerEnter(collision : Collider)
{
    if( collision.gameObject.CompareTag("playerLeg") || collision.gameObject.CompareTag("playerArm" ) )
    {
        Debug.Log("CPU RıNGO! RıNGO!"); 
    }
}
```

P.S. Also, I tried RaycastHit, and it did not work...

Comment: Did you enable AnimatePhysics?

Comment: I am currently not using animation. I created some basic models by my own, and am using them.

Comment: Is it still actual? Need more details to help you

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a silly question but, do you have `IsTrigger=true` to any of your objects? Also, both the colliding objects have a rigidbody??